Windows could not start the SQl server (SQLEXPRESS) service on Local Computer (MacOS running Windows 11 VM)
I have a common problem that I just cannot figure out after scrolling through posts expressing a similar issue. I am currently running a macOS using a virtual machine that has Windows 11. Due to what I understand are compatibility issues in the CPU architecture, I downloaded SQL Server 2019 Localdb. When I try to connect to the server, I run into the exact issue this post described:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035516/sql-server-cant-start-to-connect
My guess is that the issue is stemming from the fact that SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) is stopped in SQL Server Configuration Manager, but when I try to right click and start, I get this message:

I suspect as well that the absence of startup parameters might be relevant:

I corrected this issue by going to the Registry Editor and added the strings manually:

They were added successfully in the Configuration Manager:

But, when I try to start the service, I get the same error message as above saying that my request failed (Event ID: 17058), but this time the issue is I get an Access Denied:
initerrlog: Could not open error log file ‘c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG’. Operating system error = 5(Access is denied).
I am wondering whether my adding those parameters manually is a problem? It seems that the .mdf and .ldf are files that I don't have?
Any help would be much appreciated.
